# how to find the connection string details for mysql in IIS?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, iis-7, web-platform-installer

I installed php and mysql on my IIS 7,
Now, I can see the phpinfo() and it all works great, except, I dont know where and what are the connection string details are for mysql.

I am trying to install wordpress (via web platform installer on IIS) and everytime I try to install it, it asks for database details - I understand why its doing that, except, I dont know what they are myself.

After a lot of googling and searching, I am surprised that there are literally NO information on how to do this, no tutorials anywhere, not even bugs on this. Either that, or I'm barking up a different solar system.

Any links to tutorials on how to do this would be very helpful. But most importantly, how do I find the details about mysql?

thanks.

Comment: Your IIS has nothing to do with your MySQL. They are separate entities. The one who installs MySQL is the one who sets the passwords. If you used the installer, your username is probably `root` without password. Also, I don't understand what exactly "connection string" means to you - how do you want to connect to MySQL? Trough prompt, PHP or a GUI program?

Comment: Hi @Michael, I just want to pass on the details to wordpress, but before that I want to create an empty database there. Also want to install phpmyadmin, which needs these details...

Comment: Do yourself a favor and download a proper GUI for working with MySQL, such as SQLYog or something similar and forget that poo of PHPMyAdmin. As mentioned, your username is most likely root without password. You can search for a program called mysqlinstanceconfig.exe (or something similar, you should have it in your MySQL installation folder) - it allows you to quickly reconfigure your instance and you can reset your login credidentials with it.

Comment: Hi SQLYog is not free, unfortunately. is there something else I can find instead of that? thanks. I thought phpmyadmin was the best tool for mysql (I'm not a php developer, I'm a asp.net c# one)

Comment: Hi @Michael, I just googled for sql gui's and there are a couple of them, will try them and see where I can go with it. Can you please copy your comment to a new answer so I can accept it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do yourself a favor and download a proper GUI for working with MySQL, such as SQLYog or something similar and forget that poo of PHPMyAdmin. As mentioned, your username is most likely root without password.

You can search for a program called mysqlinstanceconfig.exe (or something similar, you should have it in your MySQL installation folder) - it allows you to quickly reconfigure your instance and you can reset your login credidentials with it.

About MySQL GUI-s: if I'm not mistaken, there's one free coming directly from MySQL but I'm not sure about that. Forget about PHPMyAdmin, it's the worst piece of code ever written and a HUGE security hole.

Answer (score 0):

As you're running a MySQL server locally, your hostname would be `localhost`, and you can use `root` as the username, and put nothing as the password.

Comment: how do I create a new empty database with that?!